# Nested createAlias() in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have to make a particular query using Hibernate.

The following classes are just a simple example, to make easier for you to understand my scenario and my goal. I made up the example while writing this post, I hope I didn't make errors (anyway don't pay attention to the errors :D).

```
class Father{
  int id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  List<Son> sonList;
}

class Son{
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Father.class)  
 @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "father")
 Father father;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "son", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 List<Toy> toyList;
}

class Toy{
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Son.class) 
 @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "son")
 Son son;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Feature", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 List<Feature> featureList;
}

class Feature{
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Toy.class)
 @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "toy") 
 Toy toy;

 boolean unisex;
}
```

I have to select from the database a `Father` with `id = 1`, with his relative `Son`, but only the sons that has a `Toy` with  `Feature.unisex = true`.

I dunno how to reach the field `Feature.unisex` of class `Toy`.

With `createAlias()` I can do:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Father.class);           
criteria.createAlias("sonList", "sonListAlias");
criteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(1));
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("sonListAlias.toyList", toyList));
```

but I can't go further. I should need something like:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Father.class);           
criteria.createAlias("sonList", "sonListAlias");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("sonListAlias.toyList.featureList.unisex", unisex));
```

but, of course, this is not the right way to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please don't use unnecessary mapping properties. I mean `targetEntity=Father.class`, `referencedColumnName = "id", name = "father"`. And  don't use names like `sonList`, just `sons`.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Father.class);           
criteria.createAlias("sonList", "son");
criteria.createAlias("son.toyList", "toy");
criteria.createAlias("toy.featureList", "feature");
criteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(1));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("feature.unisex", true));
```

If you need to eagerly fetch `sonList`, you can try to use `setFetchMode("sonList", FetchMode.JOIN)`.

If you need to

> "always" get a father and get only his sons that have toys that have
>   Feature.unisex = true

you can try to use `@Filter`

[Hibernate @Filter and @FilterJoinTable Annotation Example](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example)

But I think It will be better, if you load `sonList` in a separate request

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Son.class);           
    criteria.createAlias("father", "father");
    criteria.createAlias("toyList", "toy");
    criteria.createAlias("toy.featureList", "feature");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("father.id", 1));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("feature.unisex", true));
```

Comment: Thank you man, you've been very helpful; you solved almost all of my problems. But probably I wasn't enough clear in my post. With your query, I get a Father only when a father has a son, that has a toy, that as Feature.unisex = true. What I really need is to "always" get a father and get only his sons that have toys that have  Feature.unisex = true.
Dunno if i've been clear :D